# Acrobat JavaScript mailDoc operation failing

Tags: javascript, email, pdf, acrobat

**Goal:** I have a fillable PDF form that collects data required to send an email. In the PDF, I have a button to send the PDF, using the mailDoc function on mouse up.

```
if(app.viewerVersion < 11 )
   app.alert("Please download the latest version of Reader",1);

var cToAddr = "email@yahoo.com";
var cBCCAddr = "email@yahoo.com";
var cCCAddr = this.getField("ClientEmail").value;
var cBenAddr = this.getField("BennyEmail").value;

if(cBenAddr != "") {
    cCCAddr += ";" + cBenAddr;
}

var cSubLine = "Service Proposal " + this.getField("ServiceAddress").value + " " + this.getField("Text1").value;
var cBody = "Thank you for the opportunity. Please see attached proposal.\n" + "Save the filled form attachment for your own records";

this.mailDoc({
    bUI: true, 
    cTo: cToAddr, 
    cCc: cCCAddr, 
    cBcc: cBCCAddr,
    cSubject: cSubLine, 
    cMsg: cBody
});
```

**Error Message:**

```
GeneralError: Operation failed.
Doc.mailDoc:22:AcroForm:Email Quote:Annot1:MouseUp:Action1
```

I've followed [this guide](https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/dynamically-setting-submit-e-mail-address) and added a cBcc as they did in [this community post](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/Programmable-button-to-initiate-MailDoc-Javascript-code-not-working-on-first-attempt-q276562.aspx), but it had no impact.

The fields are accurately named, and it prompts me to sign into my email account when I press the button, so I'm not sure what is causing the issue, and can't find documentation for mailDoc to help.

Comment: What email client are you using? Acrobat/Reader is only compatible with gmail and yahoo for web clients and anything that uses MAPI on Windows.

Comment: @joelgeraci - Using a yahoo email address, and it prompted me to log in the first time I tested it (stayed logged in for those after, I assume). So I press send, it does the sending-loading bar like it's going to send, and then the debugger displays the error shown in my post.

Comment: `console.log` your variables prior to calling `mailDoc` and make sure they have the expected values. Perhaps one of your fields doesn't exist

Comment: Your code looks ok to me from a first glance (I can reproduce the error though)... You can find the documentation here: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf#G5.2237013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct.  This seems to be a bug when using Yahoo! to send the email.  When I try to send it via Outlook or Gmail it works for me (and fails on Yahoo!).

You can find the javascript documentation here: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf#G5.2237013

Comment: Thanks - changing to Outlook worked. It seems Yahoo may have some issues with MAPI compliance.